# Regression and Neural networks

Tags: regression

I'm trying to restore this function:

$$ F(x) = x*sin(\alpha x)+b; \space\space \alpha,b \in (-20,20) $$

My NN model(with Keras) is:

1 layer: GRU, 9 neurons, selu activation
2 layer: GRU, 3 neurons, selu activation
1 layer: GRU, 7 neurons, selu activation
1 layer: Dense, 1 neuron, linear activation
*kernel init he_normal for all layers*

For the training dataset I've generated function values $f(x), x \in -5..5$ (e.g. `linspace(-5,5,500)` and random **integer** values for $\alpha$ and $b$, 250 times.

Then I've selected $f[i-1]$ and $f[i]$ (previous steps) and for this "xs" the output is $f[i+1]$. So the training dataset is like:

**X**:
   first row: previous previous $f$, $\alpha$, $b$
   second row: previous $f$, $\alpha$, $b$

**Y**: 
   current $f$ value

After training over 200 epochs, mae on validation data was 0.1851.

Now if I try to predict new data it seems normal, but when I try to predict new values using previously predicted by model points it falls down and it doesn't looks like sine function at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your error is accumulating and diverging. In other words, a small error in the first prediction is leading to a larger error in your second prediction, which is leading to an even larger error in your third prediction, and so on.

With that said, [this LSTM example](https://github.com/jaungiers/LSTM-Neural-Network-for-Time-Series-Prediction) seems to do well predicting multiple future values for a sine wave.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but the question is how to avoid this effect, maybe I need more data?)